# How do I combine two keys to act as FN key with xbindkeys?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, opensuse, key-mapping, xbindkeys

I have been hammering my head on the wall for the past two days trying to figure out a way to combine two keys to execute a function with xbindkeys.

To make a long story short I have a chromebook c720 running OpenSUSE, and as you may already know chromebooks don't have Function keys but they do have hotkeys rather. 
Since I have already mapped with xbindkeys each hotkeys to do what they are supposed to do, my goal now is to combine the ctrl + hotkey to emulate the FN key.

I can map a single key with xbindkey and xmodmap to act as FN key by using

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 72 = F6'
```

however I can't seem to be able to map two to act as such.

Here's the ctrl + F6 key codes output.

```
caino@chromebook:~> xbindkeys -k
Press combination of keys or/and click under the window.
You can use one of the two lines after "NoCommand"
in $HOME/.xbindkeysrc to bind a key.
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x0 + c:72
    F6
caino@chromebook:~> xbindkeys -k
Press combination of keys or/and click under the window.
You can use one of the two lines after "NoCommand"
in $HOME/.xbindkeysrc to bind a key.
"(Scheme function)"
    m:0x4 + c:37
    Control + Control_L
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Which key or key combination are you trying to bind, and what do you want to make it do? You mention Ctrl+F6, do you want to make Ctrl+F6 do something? Or do you want some key combination to be recognized as Ctrl+F6? To see what a key combination currently sends, run the program `xev` from a terminal and press the key combination; note the KeyPress events.

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is to bind Ctrl + F6 to actually act as a F6 imput. This is a chromebook and it does not have Function Keys but rather hotkeys.